# The email address is badly formatted problem in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth and Firestore on my app and I using TextInputLayout for Login and Register screens but I got a problem it's like exception named "**The email address is badly formatted**" when I want to add new user from Register screen. I looked up but I can't find any Kotlin question about this problem I'll leave my codes below. I'm waiting your help. Have a good Codes :) .

## *LoginActivity.kt*

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val db = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    private val auth = Firebase.auth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)

        binding.tvRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this@LoginActivity)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, null)

            dialog.setContentView(view)

            val etName = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etName).toString()
            val etSurname = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etSurname).toString()
            val etMail = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etRegisterEmail).toString()
            val etPassword = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etRegisterPassword).toString()
            val etHeight = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etHeight).toString()
            val etWeight = view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etWeight).toString()
            val btnRegister = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnRegister)

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
                val user = hashMapOf<Any, String>(
                    "name" to etName,
                    "surname" to etSurname,
                    "email" to etMail,
                    "password" to etPassword,
                    "height" to etHeight,
                    "weight" to etWeight
                )
                if (etName.isNotEmpty() && etSurname.isNotEmpty() && etMail.isNotEmpty() && etPassword.isNotEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(etMail,etPassword,user)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@LoginActivity,
                        "You have to fill blanks",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
            dialog.show()
        }
    }

    private fun registerUser(email: String, password: String, user: HashMap<Any, String>) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        db.document(auth.currentUser?.email.toString()).set(user)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                                checkLogged()
                            }
                            .addOnFailureListener {
                                    Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show()
                            }
                    }.await()
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkLogged() {
        if (auth.currentUser != null) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            auth.signOut()
        }
    }
}
```

## *bottom_sheet_layout.xml* (Register Screen)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRegisterTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryDarkColor"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRegisterTitle">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/primaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etSurname"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/surname"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etName">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/primaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etRegisterEmail"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/e_mail"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:endIconTint="@color/secondaryColor"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etSurname">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etRegisterPassword"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:endIconTint="@color/secondaryColor"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etRegisterEmail">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etHeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/height"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/etWeight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etRegisterPassword">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etWeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/weight"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/etHeight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etRegisterPassword">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondaryDarkColor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="16sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etWeight" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:rotation="26"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/broccoli_png" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:rotation="26"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/broccoli_png" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:rotation="26"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/broccoli_png" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did Mokhtar's answer help?

Comment: No I can't solve problem with Mokthar's way I'll leave a kind a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
auth.currentUser?.email.toString().trim()
```

Dont forget to add `trim()`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, I think it's about TextEditLayout thing

Comment: btw I changed  **auth.currentUser?.email.toString()** to **auth.currentUser!!.uid** but the problem still continues.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't solved the problem but I changed somethings in code

---

1- Changed **hash** state to **User** named data class

2- I define etMail like:

```
val etMail =view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etRegisterEmail).editText?.text.toString()
```

3- And I carried defined properties to inside of ***btnRegister.setOnClickListener***

> ***Final Version of Code***

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val db = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    private val auth = Firebase.auth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)

        binding.tvRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this@LoginActivity)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, null)

            dialog.setContentView(view)
            val btnRegister = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnRegister)

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener {

                val etName =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etName).editText?.text.toString()
                val etSurname =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etSurname).editText?.text.toString()
                val etMail =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etRegisterEmail).editText?.text.toString()
                val etPassword =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etRegisterPassword).editText?.text.toString()
                val etHeight =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etHeight).editText?.text.toString()
                val etWeight =
                    view.findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.etWeight).editText?.text.toString()

                val user = User(etName, etSurname, etMail, etHeight, etWeight)

                registerUser(etMail, etPassword, user)
            }
            dialog.show()
        }
    }

    private fun registerUser(email: String, password: String, user: User) {
        if(email.isNotEmpty()&&password.isNotEmpty()){
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                try {
                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            db.document(auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()).set(user)
                            checkLogged()
                            Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,"Welcome",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }.await()
                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkLogged() {
        if (auth.currentUser != null) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            auth.signOut()
        }
    }
}
```